# How to Architect Database for Implementing a Commenting System

Tags: android, database

I am implementing a commenting system in my App. I need a database to hold the comments. If I make a row for each post, then i have to add all comments in one collumn and split them with some identifier. Please tell me a better way to do this.

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking. If my reply is off it's probably because you need to provide some more info. Is there one chain of comments, or many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some one comments on your app, the comments will be part of a chain of comments. So what you will store on every row will be something like this:

```
DatabaseId|PositionOfComment|Comment|DiscussionId
```

- DatabaseId - is the primary key of the table (use google)
- PositionOfComment - is an increasing number from 1, where one is the first comment, two is the second and so on
- Comment - is the actual comment the user made
- DiscussionId - is needed as a foreign key in case you have many different comment sections / discussions going on. In that case you will also have to make a discussions table. If there is only one chain of comments, then you do not need this.